# 12v / 70amp into 3v Conversion

Tags: power-supply

I have a battery 12v / 70amp & i want to convert into 3v for small led light. 
Is this circuit is suitable for my voltage requirement ?

[image]

Please Suggest me Suitable Circuit which is fullfill my requirement.

Thank You..

Comment: LEDs run based on current so what you'd rather want is a constant current source

Comment: What is your load current requirement? The circuit you have made will certainly work. The load current will determine the (heat) loss in the transistor.

Comment: @PlasmaHH the output requirement is stated as 3V, so I would assume that the "led light" needs a constant voltage input.

Comment: @kabZX: when was the last time you used a led with constant voltage sources?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Of Course i have 3v led bulb.

Comment: A simple series resistor should suffice  (12 -3) @ 20mA gives a value of about 450R so a 390R or 470R should suffice.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I was referring to a case where "LED lamp" refers to a unit with an LED and a series resistor usually mounted in a housing with a colored lens etc.

Comment: Please check the led Bulb http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/mZEofLOQzOKDyXdW4KSWBVg.jpg

Comment: Aha! the "3V LED bulb" probably has a series resistor which is sized to give the correct LED current for a 3V terminal voltage. *BUT* I have also seen types which depend on the battery internal resistance to limit current - so beware else you will fry your LED.

Comment: @ArsalanArain you need to add series resistor externally.

Comment: @PlasmaHH so I assume the circuit is Suitable for my task ?

Comment: `have a battery 12v / 70amp` More likely: *12 V,  70 **Ah** -  nominal*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the complication of a linear regulator; just use a resistor. The LED will take (say) 50mA at 3V - that's an equivalent resistance of 60 ohms. Make a potential divider with a 2nd resistor up to 12V. That 2nd resistor will drop 9V at 50mA i.e. it will be a 180 ohm, 0.5 to 1 watt resistor.

Ratio up or down the resistor value with current actually needed and check the power dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

That circuit is a huge overkill for a simple LED. Lose all of the capacitors.

We don't know the specification of "3V" LED so I presume it refers to forward voltage. So in other words, you have 12-3 = 9V to deal with.

If you want 20mA (check LED spec), R = U/I => 450R which is about the same as 470R. Bear in mind that you get 9V * 20mA = 180mW power loss over the resistor so you need 1/4W resistor or better.

If you have your heart all set to a transistor current controller, you need to do a bit more work. This would work:

[image]

Comment: Ah darn, forgot to put the LED there. It goes in before the transistor.

Comment: @ArsalanArain You could always vote for it if you like it :-P

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of everything except the battery, the LED, and the resistor.
2. Connect the battery, the resistor and the LED in series, like this:

[image]

3. Mind that you don't connect the LED backwards.